# skip the first line after if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I read a file line by line, I want to skip the first line that starts with `;` after if condition`[ word ]` but my code gives the error below. How can I fix this error?

> AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'

**Code:**

```
  for line in open(inputfile, "r").readlines():
    if "[ word ]" in line:
      line = open(inputfile, "r").next()
```

Comment: I'm a little confused, do you want to skip the first line, the fist line starting with `;`, all lines that follow a line with `;`?

Comment: I want to skip the first line starting with ;

Comment: Then what's the `if "[ word ]" in line:` condition for? Shouldn't you be checking `if line.startswith(';'):`?

Comment: There are many lines starting with `;`. I just want to ignore the one after if condition.

Comment: So you want to skip the first line that starts with `;` **after** each line that contains `[ word ]`? What if you have two lines containing `[ word ]` followed by two lines starting with `;` - do you want to skip both of those, or just one?

Comment: I want to skip the first line that starts with `;` after `[ word ]`.

Comment: @erhan for good question please edit it, with all comments you have.

Comment: Say your file contains the 4 lines `[ word ]`, `;foo`, `[ word ]` and `;bar`. Do you want to skip both `;foo` and `;bar` or only `;foo`?

Comment: I wan to skip just ;foo. By the way, I have only one `[ word ]` line in the file.

Comment: Okay, last question: Since your code never checks if a line starts with `;`, is it safe to assume that the line with `;` will be the very next line after the line with `[ word ]`?

Comment: Yes, it is safe because I have only one line with `[ word ]` in the input file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `startswith` to check how the line begins, and `continue` to move past that line

```
with open(inputfile, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(';'):
            continue
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you should just use `continue` and add variable to check is first line skiped:

```
with open(inputfile, "r") as f:
    skip_first = False
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith(';') and skip_first:
          skip_first = True
          continue
```

Comment: he will will lose the `if` like that

Comment: I can't use `with open(inputfile, "r") as f:` because I read the file from terminal (python script.py -f input.txt -o output.txt).

Comment: @erhan i don't understand why? did you try what error do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
with open(inputfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        if "[ word ]" in line:
            line = f.readline()  # 1
```

1. reassigns `line` to the next line than the one used by the `if` comparison.